# Netty PoolThreadCache seems to be occupying most of the memory. How can it be optimized?

Tags: multithreading, caching, optimization, garbage-collection, netty

[image: PoolThreadCache]

Looks like MpscArrayQueue creating lot of empty arrays. This is adding GC pressure in our high throughput, low latency application. How can it be optimized? See the above attached image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the number of caches via the `PooledByteBufAllocator` constructor.